# Cannot find module 'C:\Users\[...]\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js'

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json

[This is the error message I'm getting while updating the npm package/ just doing "npm start".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2IBG.png)

I got this issue when I was trying to start my existing react project. Then I checked either the issue is with the project or npm is not working.

Then I tried upgrading npm. I got the same issue.

Here is the log

C:\Users\DELL PC>npm install -g npm
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! path C:\Users\DELL PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\package.json
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'C:\Users\DELL PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

Can anyone help with this error?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It would be much better if you copy&pasted the error text here instead of adding link to an image.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are installing npm with npm command!!!